# How to Focus Search On One Part of a Document

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm pretty new to ElasticSearch. I'm using v2.0.0. I would like to know how to focus a search query on one portion of the document in order to answer the question "Get me (a page of 50) People who are a member of Group "Developers".

The document structure of a single person might look like something like this:

```
{
  "_index": "people",
  "_type": "employee",
  "_id": "8725",
  "_source": {
    "id": 43470,
    "firstName": "John",
    "lastName": "Smith",
    "groups": [
      {
        "id": 345,
        "name": "Developers"
      },
      {
        "id": 75432,
        "name": "Scrummasters"
      },
      {
        "id": 5789,
        "name": "UX"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

So what I want to do is look at the name of each group of each person to see if it matches what I'm looking for and if so, select the whole person. The position of what I'm looking for is obviously not static, and I can't do something simpler like

```
q=roles:developer
```

Comment: What is `roles` in your query string? You don't have it in your document. Try `q=groups.name:developers` instead.

Comment: What I meant was I cannot change the structure of the document to represent groups or roles as a comma separated string for example - Just so that searching is easier somehow. "roles" isn't in the document and never will be.

Comment: Hmm. Maybe it is possible to use "q=groups.name:Developers". I will have to try it.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, I can select employees that are in group Developers by specifying the query string as "q=groups.name:Developers". Indeed, I could also use a wildcard to get anybody in group Admin or Administrators or Admins using "q=groups.name:Admin*"

Comment: Indeed, for the full list of supported options refer [URI Search](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-uri-request.html#search-uri-request).